# is it possible to code my own application with medical material?

Tags: iphone, ipad, medical

I'm currently doing an internship in a medical laboratory

They want to buy Ipad and medical device connected to it

example: diabet tester http://www.ibgstar.us/
         blood pressure monitoring system http://www.ihealth99.com/

I'm wondering if I can code my own application that gets the data from the medical device and then handle it?

thks for your answers

Comment: AFAIK, the devices that will connect to device(iphone/pad/pod) should comply with MFI program, you can use ExternalAccessory.Framework then http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502

Comment: Yes, both of the devices you list are MFi-compliant, so they can be accessed via an iOS application. However, you will need to obtain the specific protocols that both companies use for communicating with these devices. They may or may not allow others to develop third-party applications for their devices, so you'll want to ask first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they're some step to success it .

At first you need a Hardware solution like said "Mundi".

You need to grab data from device and store them somewhere accessible (like in a BDD  with online acces).

And then the iPad application just have to connecte to the data-Source and play with it

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is `YES`.

There are many ways to get the data into the app via a network. If you would like to read from the device directly, you would have to additionally find a hardware solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this applies, but I've seen some really cool medical apps written using Harvard's SMART project.  They provide a simple but effective framework, which is independent of the Hospital Information System (like Cerner, Epic, VistA).